# How to: Spring Boot + Gradle + Jib+ Cloud Run + Cloud Build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, jib

Anyone know of any examples of deploying a Spring Boot app using **Spring Boot + Gradle + Jib + cloudbuild.yaml**?  I haven't found any so far.  The GCP docs provide only a half-baked Maven build example (not Gradle), and I can't find any **Jib docs** that cover **Gradle + cloudbuild.yaml + Spring Boot**.  So far, I can get a Jib image created and pushed to GCP Artifact Registry, but when I deploy to Cloud Run I'm getting "Could not find or load main class ...".  I'm **not** using the war plugin (as recommended by Google) so I'm guessing Jib will try to use Spring Boot's fat Jar with custom class loader, but dunno.  At this point I'm just looking for doc references and not debugging help, so any doc references for cloudbuild.yaml + Gradle + Spring Boot + Cloud Run would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: For anyone following...downgrading Spring Boot from 3.0.2 (currently latest) to 2.1.6 fixed the class loading problem with Spring.  This what the latest Jib example for Gradle + Spring Boot used https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/commit/afe98e7f23a0ea56b6b3bbde296)00280777fe75e - Since the latest Spring Boot requires Java 17+,  had targetCompatability at 17, so now getting a class version conflict, I think because I'm using Jib's default image which probably has 1.8 - Guessing that Jib doesn't yet support SpringBoot 3+ (their ex uses an outdated Spring version) - docs would be great

Comment: Got something working, https://github.com/thd-hello-world/jib-srping-boot-3-gradle-cloud-run/tree/master/examples/spring-boot - Jib abstracts so much of the containerization for you that it's very easy for you to create an image that is **not** what you ultimately want - the Jib layering process was causing the "Could not find or load main class ..." - but this is because I kept trying to build my newer Spring Boot app on their much older Spring Boot image used for their example - hope this helps save you some time

Comment: best I could find for docs:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin
and
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md